# Gradle file buildscript block

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I´m trying to build my project using gradle.
I have de build.gradle file as following:

```
plugins {
    id "fr.putnami.gwt" version "0.4.0"
    id "info.solidsoft.pitest" version "1.3.0"
    }

buildscript {

  repositories {
        mavenCentral() 
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
  }
  dependencies {
  
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:2.8.1'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.plantuml:plantuml:8001'
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.de.fntsoftware.gradle:markdown-to-pdf:1.1.0'
  }
  

}
    
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'de.fntsoftware.gradle.markdown-to-pdf'
```

When I try to execute the build task, I always get:

*all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script*

I´ve already tried to put the first block of plugins inside of the buildscript one, but nothing is working. Can someone help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

> all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script

Explains what you need to do: move the buildscript block before the plugins block. E.g.

```java
buildscript {
  repositories { ... }
  dependencies { ... }
  ...
}

plugins {
  ...
}
```

Don't put one inside the other.

However, regardless of the order, I don't think you are using the two blocks correctly in the first place.

Firstly, the `buildscript` block is for configuring dependencies used in the actual script, and not what is used for building your project. So things like junit or easymock does not make sense here. You most likely wanted to put the dependencies block outside as these are for the project.

Secondly, the `plugins` block can be seen as a newer easier way of writing `apply plugin` where you usually don't have to configure the buildscript classpath. You should use it wherever you can instead of the older and more verbose way. If you are in doubt about how to write a third-party plugin in the newer way, find it in the [Gradle Plugins Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/) and read the description there.

Try with something like this instead:

```java
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'war'
  id 'jacoco'
  id 'eclipse'
  id "fr.putnami.gwt" version "0.4.0"
  id "info.solidsoft.pitest" version "1.3.0"
  id "de.fntsoftware.gradle.markdown-to-pdf" version "1.1.0"
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral() 
}
 
dependencies {
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:2.5.2'
  testCompile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:2.8.1'
  compile 'net.sourceforge.plantuml:plantuml:8001'
}
```

Also be aware that the [Putnami GWT plugin](https://github.com/Putnami/putnami-gradle-plugin) is no longer maintained, but has an (at this time relative) [active fork](https://github.com/esoco/gwt-gradle-plugin).

Also also, `compile` is deprecated and you should use `implementation` if your version of Gradle and your plugins support it.